# Highlight years in content using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

Using `jQuery` I want to highlight the years in the string.

I have a simple list of the items. I want to wrap year in a string by `span`

```js
function getyear(val) {
  return /\d{4}/.test(val) ? val.replace(/^[^\d]*(\d{4}).*$/, '$1') : 'Now';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("li").each(function(i, v) {
    $('li').append((i + 1) + ':\t' + getyear(v) + '\n');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <ul>
    <li>Manufacturer by 332 ZX 8985 Jimba 2017</li>
    <li>Manufacturer by 22T736 Jimba 2017</li>
    <li>Manufacturer by jackson T736 hub 2017-1958 </li>
    <li>Manufacturer by Jimba Dummasa corey 2017</li>
    <li>Manufacturer by Jimba corey TCGH1922 2017</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

**Output Needed:**

```
<div class="content">
    <ul>
        <li>Manufacturer by 332 ZX 8985 Jimba <span>2017</span></li>
        <li>Manufacturer by 22T736 Jimba <span>2017</span></li>
        <li>Manufacturer by jackson T736 hub <span>2017-1953</span> </li>
        <li>Manufacturer by Jimba Dummasa corey <span>2017</span></li>
        <li>Manufacturer by Jimba corey TCGH1922 <span>2000</span></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: @amit  try to answer the question that would help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `regex` you are using works for dates string only not for extracting the year from text see below the solution works for you assuming that the `YEAR` will always be on the end on the string and in 4 digit format. I have extracted the year hope you can wrap it in a `span` now.

```js
function getyear(node) {
  let val = node.text().trim();
  let newspan = '';
  let newNode = '';

  let numbersOnly = val.replace(/[^0-9\-]+/g, '|')
  let numberArr = numbersOnly.split('|');
  numberArr = numberArr.clean("");

  numberArr.forEach(function(v) {
    //console.log(v.match(/^\d{4}$/));
    if (v.length == 4 || v.length == 9) {
      val = val.replace(v, "<span class='my-label'>" + v + "</span>");
    }
  });
  return val;
}

Array.prototype.clean = function(deleteValue) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] == deleteValue) {
      this.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return this;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mark").click(function() {
    jQuery("li").each(function(i, v) {
      //$('li').append((i + 1) + ':\t' + getyear(v) + '\n');
      //getyear($(this));
      $(this).html(getyear($(this)));
    });
  });

});

/*previously used solution if year appear only in the end of string*/
function getyearOLD(node) {
  let val = node.text().trim();
  let newspan = '';
  let newNode = '';
  if (val.charAt(val.length - 5) == '-') {
    newspan = ' <span class="my-label">' + val.substr(val.length - 9) + '</span>';
    newNode = val.substr(0, val.length - 9) + newspan;
  } else {

    newspan = ' <span class="my-label">' + val.substr(val.length - 4) + '</span>';
    newNode = val.substr(0, val.length - 9) + newspan;
  }
  //return val.substr(val.length - 4);
  //node.text(newNode);
  return newNode;

}
```

```css
.my-label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <ul>
    <li>Manufacturer by 332 ZX 8985 Jimba 2017</li>
    <li>Manufacturer by 22T736 Jimba 2017</li>
    <li>Manufacturer by jackson T736 hub 2017-1958 </li>
    <li>Manufacturer by Jimba Dummasa corey 2017</li>
    <li>Manufacturer by Jimba corey TCGH1922 2017</li>
  </ul>

</div>

<input type="button" value="mark years" id="mark" />
```

Comment: not working where this is value of year like   2017-1958

Comment: i am able to do that but that's not i am looking for.  Can you acheive what i am looking for?

Comment: @jack i just updated my answer and did just what you wanated , hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Hi,  thanks for your efforts but still not proper. for this case it doesn't work:   <li>Manufacturer by 2017-1958 jackson T736 hub  </li>

Comment: well i told that in start that i assume the year is in the end, if it is going to be anywhere in the. string that is going to be real hard to do it you gotta have to limit some thing atleast keep year at a specific place in all the li

Comment: Yes but thing is name is generating dynamically.  i am not sure where year value will populate.  that's the main concern.  I am front end developer with experience in react, backbone and node despite not able to find answer of it.!!! if you can do i would be happy

Comment: Ok! Thanks for your help! i really like your dedication.

Comment: well tried alot but this does not seem to be possible without limiting the position of the year or year range, if you see the demo now, it can detect years and year range anywhere in the string but at the same time iif there is a model number that is also 4 digits and can be `1992` for example which is a valid year too, then it also becomes highlighted, thats as far as you can go with the scenario you are going on with, you HAVE TO KEEP years in a dedicated place inside a string. I have kept the old function inside the code snippet so that if the plan changes you can use it.@jack

Answer (score 0):

> Kind of kitchen coding answer-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('ul > li').each(function(index) {
    var text = $(this).text();
    var year = '';
    for (i = text.length - 1; i > text.length - 5; i--) {
        year += text[i];
    }
    year = year.split("").reverse().join("");
    if (text[i] === '-') {
        year = text.slice(i - 5, i) + '-' + year;
        text = text.slice(0, text.length - 9);
    } else {
        text = text.slice(0, text.length - 4);
    }

    $(this).html(text + '<span>' + year + '</span>');
});
</script>
```

Comment: not working properly.  what if year is in middle of the string?  Also when there are 2times value then  it doesn't work properly.    1995-2015

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the possible soluiton.
It detects the year if it is four digit and starts with either 1 or 2.

```js
$('.content li').each(function(){
 
  var el, html, newHtml;
  
  // current element
  el = $(this);
  
  // current element HTML
  html = el.html();
  
  // replace years
  newHtml = html.replace(/(1|2)\d\d\d(?=\s)?/g, function( year ){
    return '<span class="year">' + year + '</span>';
  });
  
  el.html( newHtml ); 
});
```

```css
body{
  font-family:'Arial';
 }
 
.year{
  font-weight:bold;
  color:tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
   <ul>
    <li>Manufacturer by 332 ZX 8985 Jimba 2017</li>
    <li>Manufacturer by 22T736 Jimba 2017</li>
     <li>Manufacturer by jackson T736 hub  2017-1958 </li>
    <li>Manufacturer by Jimba Dummasa corey 2017</li>
    <li>Manufacturer by Jimba corey TCGH1922 2017</li>
    <li>Multiple years like 2017 and 2016 both will be marked</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: your code always look for the year value at the end.  Year value can be anywhere.   for this  <li>Manufacturer by Jimba 2017 - 2019 corey TCGH1922 </li>   it will not detect year

Comment: @jack Check answer, it is more cleaner now

Comment: thanks for your reply.  i did check and there is small issue  2017-1958  in this format  dash between 2 years is not wrapped up in span.  it should  be wrapped  like   <span>2017</span><span>-</span><span>1958</span>  or <span>1957-2910</span>

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnsb').on('click', function () {
            var data1 = "";
            var list_li = new Array();
            var count = 0;
            $('li').each(function (index) {
                var data = ($(this).text()).trim();
                var year = data.substr(data.lastIndexOf(' ') + ' '.length).trim();
                data = '<li>' + data + '</li>';
                data = data.replace(year, '<label style="color:red;">' + year + '</label>');
                data1 += data;
            });

            $('.content').html('<ul>' + data1 + '</ul>');
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>Manufacturer by 332 ZX 8985 Jimba 2017</li>
            <li>Manufacturer by 22T736 Jimba 2017</li>
            <li>Manufacturer by jackson T736 hub 2017-1958 </li>
            <li>Manufacturer by Jimba Dummasa corey 2017</li>
            <li>Manufacturer by Jimba corey TCGH1922 2017</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="btnsb" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't work when values likes:   <li>Manufacturer 2017-2005 by 332 ZX 8985 Jimba</li>

Comment: yes i knw ,given post was on;y true for given set of input !!!thank u for ur comment